# How to load json data in web application UI

Tags: jmeter

I have one drop down list in my application. Each drop down option is one individual JSON POST request. Even i select any drop down option (json request), data will load but URL won't change.

I want to load from my application UI. Can anyone help me to do performance testing from Web application UI.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot perform a load test from the web browser as browser simply neither has the relevant functionality to conduct high loads nor provides reports containing [performance metrics](http://www.monitis.com/blog/most-important-metrics-for-your-website-performance/)

The only solution I can think of is [`Follow Me` mode of the JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001235585-Chrome-Extension-FollowMe) where you can choose how many users will repeat each your online step.

---

Given [`jmeter`](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/tags/jmeter/info) tag of your question you might also want to know how to simulate the load using [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) tool The easiest way is to record the requests using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), even if the URL doesn't change browser still generates [HTTP Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) for each dropdown selection event and JMeter is capable of recording and replaying of HTTP requests.